# Incorrect syntax near '<' in SQL Server Scalar Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the requirement:

Find all teachers whose FirstName length is less than 5 and the first 3 characters of their FirstName and LastName are the same

I tried this query (Scalar Function):

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_TeacherFirstName (@TeacherID int)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(20)
SELECT @Result = LEN(FirstName) < 5 AND LEFT(FirstName,3) = LEFT(LastName,3)
FROM dbo.Teacher
WHERE @TeacherID = ID

RETURN @Result 
END
```

To call function:

```
--CALL FUNCTION
select *, dbo.fn_TeacherFirstName (ID) AS Result
from dbo.Teacher t
```

But, when I execute first query, it shows error:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This `LEN(FirstName) < 5 AND LEFT(FirstName,3) = LEFT(LastName,3)` is not valid on its own. In SQL Server you can't evaluate logical expression like you can in C#. I expect you meant to put it inside a `case` expression.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the function, that's invalid syntax whether there's a function involved or not.

Comment: @Aaron Betrand is right. Regardless, just replace "AND" with "&" if you're trying to return the logical result.  e.g. "select 1 & 1" returns 1 ... "select 1 & 0" returns 0.  "select 1 AND 1"  returns that error.

Comment: That won't fix it, @JohnJoseph ,`&` is a bitwise and, it has even less reason to be there than the expression the OP has used.

Comment: Honestly, this is a poor choice of design anyway; if you need the first name of teaxher then `JOIN` to the appropriate table. Don't treat SQL like a programming language, it isn't one. Making generic functions to use everywhere hinders performance, rather than improves it.

Comment: why using a stored function and not either a stored procedure or a simple view?

Comment: Thanks, Larnu, that's correct. Also agree 100% with your "poor design" assessment. My advice to OP is to use Case...When syntax to get the result. Something like: SELECT @Result = case when LEN(FirstName) < 5 AND LEFT(FirstName,3) = LEFT(LastName,3) then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal query, not a function. Also there is no `boolean` type in SQL Server, use `bit` instead.

```sql
SELECT *,
  Result = CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(t.FirstName) < 5 AND LEFT(t.FirstName, 3) = LEFT(t.LastName, 3) THEN 1 END AS bit)
FROM dbo.Teacher t
```